# Using an "if" condition on "for"

Tags: twig, symfony4

I wanted to put into production my symfony 4 application, everything is going well but on some pages I have an error 500, I could find where the problem comes from but I don't understand how to solve it.

```
{% for articleUps in articleUp if articleUps.statut == "épinglé" %}
                    <div class="article">
                        <img src="{{ asset('assets/avatar/')~articleUps.user.image }}"
                             class="card-img-top photo rounded-circle">
                        <i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i><a href="{{ path('forum_articles', {'id': articleUps.id , 'slug': articleUps.slug }) }}">{{ articleUps.sujet }}</a><br>
                        <strong>Crée le {{articleUps.createdAt|localizeddate('none', 'none', 'fr', null, 'EEEE d MMMM Y') }} • par<a href="{{ path('app_profil', {'username': articleUps.user.username}) }} ">{{ articleUps.user.username }}</a></strong>
                        {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                            <a href="{{ path('article_edit', {'id': articleUps.id}) }}" class="lien">editer</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                {% endfor %}
```

so I get this error in the symfony log:

```
[2020-01-05 17:26:49] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Using an "if" condition on "for" tag in "forum/categories.html.twig" at line 91 is deprecated since Twig 2.10.0, use a "filter" filter or an "if" condition inside the "for" body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop). {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Using an \"if\" condition on \"for\" tag in \"forum/categories.html.twig\" at line 91 is deprecated since Twig 2.10.0, use a \"filter\" filter or an \"if\" condition inside the \"for\" body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop). at /var/www/html/ara.issoire-web.fr/vendor/twig/twig/src/TokenParser/ForTokenParser.php:46)"} []
```

how can i do that there are no more bugs in production ?

I changed my condition, here is the news that still works in dev but not in production:

```
{% for articleUps in articleUp %}
                        {% if articleUps.statut == "épinglé"  %}
                        <div class="article">
                            <img src="{{ asset('assets/avatar/')~articleUps.user.image }}"
                                 class="card-img-top photo rounded-circle">
                            <i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i><a href="{{ path('forum_articles', {'id': articleUps.id , 'slug': articleUps.slug }) }}">{{ articleUps.sujet }}</a><br>
                            <strong>Crée le {{articleUps.createdAt|localizeddate('none', 'none', 'fr', null, 'EEEE d MMMM Y') }} • par<a href="{{ path('app_profil', {'username': articleUps.user.username}) }} ">{{ articleUps.user.username }}</a></strong>
                            {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                                <a href="{{ path('article_edit', {'id': articleUps.id}) }}" class="lien">editer</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's true that you have to move the `if` inside the `for` from now on - It should work on your production platform as well. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/2csgni), make sure you've cleaned the cache properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a warning - Twig v2 has no deprecated the `if` on a `for` statement, but it's still working OK, until you upgrade to the next major version of Twig. Symfony, and the related tools are very good about such deprecations.

As for ensuring you have no other bugs in production - the logs (in dev, and production) will show where there are other issues for deprecations, or problems - it would be very useful to enable more logging, ideally with the 'fingers-crossed' error handler. This keeps all the logging that is available for a request - but only writes them all to the log files if there is an error.

As for finding problems before they exist - tests. Unit tests, functional & integrations.

> As of Twig 2.10, use the filter filter instead, or an if condition inside the for body (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop and you are not using the loop variable).
>   - https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html

Comment: there is not an alternative to solve my problem? there is only this error, i have Twig V 2.7

Comment: I changed my condition, here is the news that still works in dev but not in production